# VM Instance Password Expired

Tags: google-compute-engine

So, I ignored and then forgot about the notice that my password would expire in 2 days. Now those 2 days have passed, and when I attempt to remote to the instance, I get the error that my credentials did not work. Any way to fix this, without needing to delete and recreate the instance? Lesson learned - next time I'll make it a priority to change the password reset protocol...

P.S. On another forum someone suggested using localhost\ in front of the account name, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kam - thank you for your suggestion! It turned out that I didn't need it afterall though.

Apparently part of the problem is that I'm using the Chrome RDP extension to connect. So I just created a Windows RDP connection using the link in the Google Developers Console, so I could edit it and add that line. I decided to test it before modifying, and that brought me to a window with the option to change my password, which the Chrome RDP extension did not do.

Answer (score 0):

Open your RDP file in Notepad, add the following line and save it.

enablecredsspsupport:i:0

Connect to your server and change the expired password.